# Binary file uploaded with Git LFS doesn't work

Tags: github, binaryfiles, git-lfs

So, yesterday I wanted to upload a MSI file (for my [Electron](https://electronjs.org) video game) on GitHub, but the file was over 100MB, so I used [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com) to upload it.

Then, I downloaded the MSI file from GitHub to see if it works. It should've shown this:
[image: Parakeet Simulator (Machine - MSI) Setup]

But, instead I get this:
[image: This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.]

This is my `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.exe filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.msi filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

This is my repo: [@EntityPlantt/parakeet-simulator](https://github.com/EntityPlantt/parakeet-simulator)
What do I do?

#### Edit

It turns out that the file looked something like this:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:50937b5a534292b38a0329c305d12b2da99b86281fd8841ac07f8bf0f38359fb
size 177451008
```

It wasn't even binary!
When I download it thru GitHub Pages with [this link](https://entityplantt.github.io/parakeet-simulator/msi/Parakeet%20Simulator.msi), the above thing shows up, and when I download it thru GitHub's Raw option, via [this link](https://github.com/EntityPlantt/parakeet-simulator/raw/main/msi/Parakeet%20Simulator.msi), it works. But, why?

Answer (score 0):

When using Git LFS, you need to have run `git lfs install` at least once on your machine (for each individual user).  That installs the hooks and filters required for Git LFS to work.

If you haven't done that, do that, and then you should be able to fix your repository by doing `git lfs pull` to pull the large files.  If you're using a tarball or zip file link on GitHub, then you have to go into the settings and enable LFS support in archives, since by default LFS files are not included.